# SQL clean History repeated intermediate values

Tags: sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I've noticed that my table has multiple redundant values that should be cleaned, it's a table that records price changes, so I would like to clean the following way:

```
product | price | date
------------------------
1       | 1     | 1
1       | 1     | 2
1       | 1     | 3
1       | 1     | 4
2       | 77    | 5
1       | 1     | 6
1       | 2     | 7
1       | 2     | 8
1       | 1     | 9
1       | 1     | 10
1       | 1     | 11
1       | 1     | 12
1       | 3     | 13
```

To this:

```
product | price | date
------------------------
1       | 1     | 1
2       | 77    | 5
1       | 2     | 7
1       | 1     | 9
1       | 3     | 13
```

Also assume that in this case the column `id` is the same as `date`.

`SELECT DISTINCT ON (product, price)` won't work because it would ignore either the `product` `1` change on day `9` or `1`,
The problem is that I want to group by `product`,`price` but only in certain intervals according to relevant changes by `date`.

Even it's possible to order the `product` it's hard to ignore `date` and `price` change order.

The objective is to delete all ids that are not in the intended result table.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/) `distinct on ()` suggests you are using Postgres?

Comment: What happened to 1/6 in your results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem, where you want to group together adjacent rows of the same product having the same price.

Here is one approach using the difference between row numbers to define the groups

```
select product, price, min(date) date
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by product order by date) rn1,
        row_number() over(partition by product, price order by date) rn2
    from mytable t
) t
group by product, price, rn1 - rn2
order by min(date)
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b7df9c940334cc25298760e589d4b07b)**:

```
product | price | date
------: | ----: | ---:
      1 |     1 |    1
      2 |    77 |    5
      1 |     2 |    7
      1 |     1 |    9
      1 |     3 |   13
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete duplicate rows with keeping on (use min() or max() to keep the oldest / newest row)

you can filter which columns should determine duplicates by grouping

```
DELETE FROM MyTable WHERE RowId NOT IN (SELECT MIN(RowId) FROM MyTable GROUP BY Col1, Col2, Col3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the first row when the price changes.  If so, I recommend `lag()`:

```
select t.product, t.product, t.price
from (select t.*,
             lag(price) over (partition by product order by date) as prev_price
      from t
     ) t
where prev_price is null or prev_price <> price;
```

No aggregation is necessary.  This solution should be than a solution using aggregation as well as window functions.